Ceph OSD rebalancing/redistribution of data
I'm new to ceph and I'm experimenting to find out, how it works. I started with a 3 node cluster where each node got one OSD (2x 500GB, 1x 1TB). I created the pool and the filesystem, mounted the filesystem and filling it with data. All three OSDs filled up evenly and when the pool reached 70% I added two 1TB OSDs (each on the node with 500GB). Now I expected some activity to rebalance the fill level of the OSDs, but nothing special happend. The new OSDs got some data, but the 500GB OSDs ran into 95%, the pool reached 100%, everything got stuck with 2 OSDs filld up just 20% and 80% free space?
I searched the documentation how to initiate the rebalance/redistribution by hand but was unable to find anything.
Can someone please point me to the docs how I can expand the capacity of the pool without such problems.

One thing to keep in mind is that adding new OSDs and the following rebalancing process takes some more space during the backfilling. Is your autoscaler turned on? Can you share ceph osd pool autoscale-status and ceph df? If the number of PGs isn't adjusted (either manually or by the autoscaler), the PG distribution won't be optimized too much. ceph balancer status could also provide some useful information as well as ceph osd tree.

Thanks for your response. In the mean time, I started over with a new cluster, reef instead of quincy, and when using RBD instead of filesystem, the rebalancing works as expected. Next step is testing the filesystem (it will take some time). I'm collecting various ceph outputs for later analysis and discussion.
